# How to reload a perticular area in html once the form updated

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a form I need to update the profle picture using Ajax.... Once it get uploaded the area needs to be change without refreshing the page

Here is my html

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form data-action="{% url 'user-profileupdate' %}"  id="profile-file-upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <div class="avatar-upload">
                                <div class="avatar-edit">
                                     <input name="input_file" type="file" id="profile-pic-upload" />
                                    <label for="profile-pic-upload"></label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="avatar-preview">
                                    {% if user_profile.avatar %}
                                        <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url('{{user_profile.profile_pic}}');"></div>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <div id="imagePreview" style="background-image: url('{% static 'assets/img/user-64x.png' %}');"></div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is the javascript part

```
$("#profile-pic-upload").change(function () {
    var data = new FormData();
    var file = this.files[0];
    data.append("file", file);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        url: $("#profile-file-upload").data('action'),
        cache: false,
        success: function (data, status) {
            $("#imagePreview").load(" #imagePreview")
            if (data['status'] == true) {
                toastr.success(data.msg);
                $('#profile-pic-upload').val('');
            }
            else {
                toastr.error(data.msg);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Currently a toster is updating in the successfunction

I need to update the image via ajax success

Comment: what is the ajax response? add your view in your question.

Comment: The response that getting from the view is 

{status: true, msg: "Profile Picture Updated Successfully.", profile_pic: "s3-bucket url"}

Comment: try `document.getElementById("imagePreview").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + data['profile_pic'] + )';`

Comment: document.getElementById("imagePreview").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + data['profile_pic'] + ')';
THis will ont work